# Force SFTP user to login to specific dir

Tags: chroot, sshd

The end goal here is to have an sftp user that logs into /home/user1/data

I have followed the instructions at the link below and they do work:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-sftp-only-user-accounts-on-centos-7

I created a dir /home/user1/data, and if I try to change the ChrootDirectory value in the sshd_config from %h to /home/user1/data, my logins fail.

I need the user to login to that specific directory, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Been a long time andno longer have the system to check, but IIRC I did it by making the user's home dir under the chroot, ie, if you have `/home/user1` then chrooting them to `/home`.  Set shell to /bin/false or similar, etc put them in a group and use the group as your chroot on the sshd_config.  Also you have to use the built-in sftp subsystem for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ChrootDirectory back to %h, then set the home directory  of user1 to /data. This assumes /home/user1 has a filesystem structure appropriate to chroot. You might need to modify the user1 home directory both in /etc/passwd, and in /home/user1/etc/passwd.

This wont lock user1 into the /home/user1/data directory, but that is where they will default to when logged in.